# Ember App Requests to Rails App -- Cross Domain?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, cross-domain, localhost

I have two separate apps, an ember app and a rails app on the same server. Right now, I'm testing locally.

My Ember requests are not going out to the rails (localhost:3000). I cannot seem to figure out if that's happening because it thinks that it is a cross-domain request. Will it be considered a cross-domain request, even though they're on the same server? If so, is there anyway to avoid this cross-domain request since they are on the same server without compromising security? Or do I need to stick to JSONP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, a request to a different port is a cross-domain request. The browser is making a preflight OPTIONS request (CORS) and not getting an answer. It is then dropping the original request. You need to have the server respond with the proper CORS headers to this OPTIONS request. The browser will then make the orignal request.

Here is [more information on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Here is the code from my application controller:

```
class V1::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers, :log_user

# respond to options requests with blank text/plain as per spec
def cors_preflight_check
  logger.info ">>> responding to CORS request"
  render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
end

# For all responses in this controller, return the CORS access control headers. 
def cors_set_access_control_headers
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-AUTH-TOKEN, X-API-VERSION, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
  headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
end
```

And from routes.rb:

```
match '/*path' => 'application#cors_preflight_check', :via => :options
```

There is also a rack plugin that can handle this: [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors)

Comment: I'm using `rack-cors` but again, when running a request my rails server doesn't show anything. Do Cross-Domain requests show up on the Rails server at all and then get rejected, or does AJAX reject them upfront before they ever get sent?

Comment: What's the point of `cors` if `AJAX` blocks cross-domain requests before they ever get sent?

Comment: AJAX always sends the pre-flight OPTIONS request for cross-domain requests. Some browser debug tools do not show this. I couldn't get rak-cors to work so I implemented the OPTIONS request handling myself.

Answer (score 0):

You dont say what platform you're running on, but the best solution for this kind of thing Ive found is tape

https://github.com/metajack/tape

This will allow you to set up a little reverse proxy - and map a url to your rails app, whilst serving your JS.

Different ports, are considered different domains by the security sandbox, thus you will need a reverse proxy in place, if you are serving your ember, and rails separately.

Comment: My local environment is OS X but I will be deploying on Linux. I will take a look at that. Answering your question, each app is served separately.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a couple of options depending if your app's are running in development or production mode, this are:

**Development mode only**

- If you are using `chrome` or `chromium` as your develpment browser you could start it with the flag `--args --disable-web-security`

**Development and production mode**

- Use `jsonp` as you already mentioned
- Add to your server configuration Cross-Origin Request headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` since you are using rails have a look [here](http://spinejs.com/docs/rails_cont).
- Serve your app's under the same domain & port variing only on the path `http://myhost.com/app1`, `http://myhost.com/app2` etc.

Hope it helps.